# RXJS conditional operator simplification

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this working code:

```
import { timer, take, pipe, map, mergeMap, iif, of } from 'rxjs'

const double = () => {
  return pipe(
    map((x: number) => x * 2)
  )
} 

const triple = () => {
  return pipe(
    map((x: number) => x * 3)
  )
}

timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  take(4),
  mergeMap(x => iif(() => x <= 1, of(x).pipe(double()), of(x).pipe(triple())))
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log('output', x)
})
```

Here is a [working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qaqerw?file=index.ts).

Output as expected is:

```
output 0
output 2
output 6
output 9
```

Only one question. This line is pretty verbose:

```
mergeMap(x => iif(() => x <= 1, of(x).pipe(double()), of(x).pipe(triple())))
```

Is it possible to simplify this line?

Comment: You could move the `of` to the function `const double = (x: number) => of(x).pipe(map((x: number) => x * 2));` then in the `iif` do `iif(..., double(x), triple(x))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of making `double` and `triple` custom operators, you could simply make them functions and just use `map`:

```js
const double = (x: number) => x * 2;
const triple = (x: number) => x * 3;

timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  take(4),
  map(x => (x <= 1 ? double(x) : triple(x)))
);
```

If the modifications come from an observable source, you can use a function that returns an observable instead with `mergeMap`:

```js
const double$ = (x: number) => of(x * 2);
const triple$ = (x: number) => of(x * 3);

timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  take(4),
  mergeMap(x => x <= 1 ? double$(x) : triple$(x))
);
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-72520667?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100)

Answer (score 1):

It can be further boiled down to this

```
timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  take(4),
  map(x => x*(x <= 1?2 : 3))
);
```